# Cannot validate, with novalidate option

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi I was inserting some date do my table. For some reasons I had to disable my constraint. The constraint was associated with index. I. ve used this line of code:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DISABLE CONSTRAINT "my_constraint" drop index
```

And my_constraint is in disable state.
No I' d like to enable this constraint, but after calling this line:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ENABLE NOVALIDATE CONSTRAINT "my_constraint";\
```

I recive an error:

> ORA-02299: cannot validate (USER.my_constraint) -  - duplicate keys found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have non-unique values with a unique index.  But you can have non-unique values with a unique constraint that is enforced by a non-unique index.  Even if you initially created a non-unique index, the `drop index` and `enable` syntax will try to recreate a unique index unless you provide more details in the `using index` section.

For example:

```
SQL> create table my_table(my_column number,
  2     constraint my_constraint unique (my_column));

Table created.

SQL> alter table my_table disable constraint my_constraint drop index;

Table altered.

SQL> insert into my_table select 1 from dual union all select 1 from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> alter table my_table enable novalidate constraint my_constraint;
alter table my_table enable novalidate constraint my_constraint
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02299: cannot validate (USER.MY_CONSTRAINT) - duplicate keys found


SQL> alter table my_table enable novalidate constraint my_constraint
  2     using index (create index my_index on my_table(my_column));

Table altered.

SQL> --The constraint is enforced, even though other rows violate it.
SQL> insert into my_table values(1);
insert into my_table values(1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (USER.MY_CONSTRAINT) violated
```

Answer (score 0):

When you inserted the rows into your table you violated the constraint, looks like it is a unique constraint based on the error message "duplicate keys found"

check what columns the constraint is based on, and then do a quick query like the following to see if you have any rows with duplicates (columna and columnb are the columns in your unique constraint)

SELECT columna, columnb COUNT(*)
FROM mytable
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

You won't be able to enable the unique constraint until all the rows in the table meet the rules of the constraint.

Comment: What if  I' d like to have duplicates?

Comment: Then it isn't unique, and your index should be a non-unique index.