# Create constraint in alter table without checking existing data

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, constraints, unique, unique-constraint

I'm trying to create a constraint on the **OE.PRODUCT_INFORMATION** table which is delivered with Oracle 11g R2.
The constraint should make the **PRODUCT_NAME** unique.

I've tried it with the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE PRODUCT_INFORMATION
  ADD CONSTRAINT PRINF_NAME_UNIQUE UNIQUE (PRODUCT_NAME);
```

The problem is, that in the **OE.PRODUCT_INFORMATION** there are already product names which currently exist more than twice.
Executing the code above throws the following error:

```
an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
duplicate key values.
```

Is there a possibility that a new created constraint won't be used on existing table data?
I've already tried the `DISABLED` keyword. But when I enable the constraint then I receive the same error message.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you asking? If you have duplicate values in a column then you cannot enforce a UNIQUE constraint on it. You must first delete the duplicates before then adding your constraint.

Comment: Thank you. That was actually the question; if there is a way to create (via alter table) a constraint without checking existing data.

Comment: @Ollie: actually, it *is* possible to have a unique constraint on a column with duplicate values in it...

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, nice thread necromancy but you're two years too late! See jonearles' comment and link on my answer

Comment: I would update your answer then, because this Q is being referenced elsewhere.

Comment: Fair point, will do Jeffrey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to enforce some sort of uniqueness for all future entries whilst keeping your current duplicates you cannot use a UNIQUE constraint.

You could use a trigger on the table to check the value to be inserted against the current table values and if it already exists, prevent the insert.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm

or you could just remove the duplicate values and then enfoce your UNIQUE constraint.

EDIT: After Jonearles and Jeffrey Kemp's comments, I'll add that you can actually enable a unique constraint on a table with duplicate values present using the `NOVALIDATE` clause but you'd not be able to have a unique index on that constrained column.

See Tom Kyte's explanation [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:8806498660292).

However, I would still worry about how obvious the intent was to future people who have to support the database. From a support perspective, it'd be more obvious to either remove the duplicates or use the trigger to make your intent clear.
YMMV

Comment: You can use a unique constraint, but you can't use a unique index.  See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981221/cannot-validate-with-novalidate-option/8005259#8005259

Comment: Jonearles, thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't thought of it!(+1) My only concern would be in the support of the constraint. Any new person supporting the DB would have to know of it or they might run into issues. With the trigger it is obvious what is happning (if a little less elegant).

Answer (score 10):

You can certainly create a constraint which will validate any newly inserted or updated records, but which will not be validated against old existing data, using the `NOVALIDATE` keyword, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE PRODUCT_INFORMATION
  ADD CONSTRAINT PRINF_NAME_UNIQUE UNIQUE (PRODUCT_NAME)
  NOVALIDATE;
```

If there is no index on the column, this command will create a non-unique index on the column.

Comment: +1 yes this works at oracle alter table tes MODIFY (call_type4 NUMBER default 0 NOT NULL NOVALIDATE);

Answer (score 0):

You can use deferrable .

```
ALTER TABLE PRODUCT_INFORMATION
  ADD CONSTRAINT PRINF_NAME_UNIQUE UNIQUE (PRODUCT_NAME)
deferrable initially deferred NOVALIDATE;
```

Comment: Could you (or anyone else) please explain a little more about the "initially deferred" clause. I'm searching about this modifier but cannot fully understand it.

Comment: Deferring a constraint only defers validation until COMMIT. This won't help if you want the data to be inserted/updated and committed.