# Inserting data into table in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I used the following script to create a table in oracle

```
CREATE TABLE  STAFF_LVL 
   (
    STAFF_LEVEL NUMBER(1,0), 
    MANAGER VARCHAR2(10), 
    OPERATOR VARCHAR2(10), 
    ENGINEER VARCHAR2(10), 
    PRIMARY KEY (STAFF_LEVEL) ENABLE
   );
```

However when I insert the following dat it doesn't work because 2 of the rows are the same

```
BEGIN
insert into staff_lvl values (1,'N','N','Y');
insert into staff_lvl values (3,'N','Y','Y');
insert into staff_lvl values (7,'Y','Y','Y');
insert into staff_lvl values (3,'N','Y','Y');
END;
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Yes, don't insert duplicates. What is it that you want?

Comment: It is for a uni project and this is the data I have to insert but staff_level is to be the primary key, Thanks Ross

Comment: If it's a primary key, it cannot have duplicates.

Comment: Primary keys can have duplicates, and even null values.  You must create or enable the constraint after you insert the data, use NOVALIDATE, and use a non-unique index.  But doing that is probably a bad idea 99.9% of the time.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981221/cannot-validate-with-novalidate-option/8005259#8005259 and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993585/create-constraint-in-alter-table-without-checking-existing-data/7996608#comment9795187_7996608
(Is it a coincidence that this question keeps coming up lately, or are you all in the same class?)

Answer (score 1):

As you say it is for a uni project, and you HAVE to have `STAFF_LEVEL` as a primary key...

Does it say that `STAFF_LEVEL` is the ONLY column to be in the PRIMARY KEY?

You could create a composite PK with:

```
CREATE TABLE  STAFF_LVL
 (
  STAFF_LEVEL NUMBER(1,0),
  MANAGER VARCHAR2(10),
  OPERATOR VARCHAR2(10),
  ENGINEER VARCHAR2(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (STAFF_LEVEL, MANAGER, OPERATOR, ENGINEER) ENABLE
);
```

Thereby allowing youe entry of two `STAFF_LEVEL` values of 3 as long as they didn't have the same values for the other columns. 
As it is though your data would still cause an issue.

Are you mandated the columns?

Could you add a generated PK column based upon a sequence?

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE  STAFF_LVL
 (
  ID NUMBER,
  STAFF_LEVEL NUMBER(1,0),
  MANAGER VARCHAR2(10),
  OPERATOR VARCHAR2(10),
  ENGINEER VARCHAR2(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID, STAFF_LEVEL) ENABLE
); 

CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 1;

insert into staff_lvl values (id_seq.nextval, 1,'N','N','Y');
insert into staff_lvl values (id_seq.nextval, 3,'N','Y','Y');
insert into staff_lvl values (id_seq.nextval, 7,'Y','Y','Y');
insert into staff_lvl values (id_seq.nextval, 3,'N','Y','Y');
```

Fundamentaly the PK HAS to be unique though.

Being cheeky, if you are mandated the columns, the data (which isn't unique) and the PK column, you could create the table, primary key and just disable the PK. It fulfills the criteria for your project (and is awful use of the DB) but would allow non-unique data whilst "technically" still having a PK on the table (even though it is disabled)...

Answer (score 0):

You have declared STAFF_LEVEL as the primary key. That means you have asked the database to make sure all rows in the table have a unique value for STAFF_LEVEL. Yet you try to insert two different rows with the same level. That's what the prevents you from inserting it.

STAFF_LEVEL doesn't look like it should be unique or serve as the primary key. So remove the primary key and you'll be able to insert the row.

(And next time, please provide the exact error message.)