# create a unique constraint on table column on Existing Table with records

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, ddl

Is it possible to create a unique constraint on table column on Existing Table with records?

```
ALTER TABLE Persons ADD UNIQUE (P_Id)
```

What will happen if the table has data and some of the data in `P_Id` is not unique?

Comment: I don't have an oracle db installed. I tried to do it using http://sqlfiddle.com but got some errors that I don't think related to this.

Comment: Show us what you tried in SQL Fiddle, and making fixing that the topic of your question.

Comment: CREATE TABLE persons
(p_id VARCHAR(10), city VARCHAR(10), country VARCHAR(10));      


insert into persons (p_id, city,country) values ("one", "two", "three");    

ERROR:ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: You shouldn't have double-quotes around the values: `'one'` not `"one"` etc.. You've accidentally used quoted identifiers. This has nothing to do with what you asked though. Also SQL Fiddle is useful, but if you're trying to learn Oracle you'd be better off with your own DB. You can get pre-built VMs to play around with so you don't have to worry about installation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you will try to add a unique key on a column which does not have unique values then you will get an ORA: error. However you can overcome this you two ways as mentioned below.

WAY 1:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_NAME UNIQUE (FIELD_NAME) DEFERRABLE NOVALIDATE;
```

WAY 2 :

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRIANT_NAME UNIQUE (FIELD_NAME) DISABLE;

ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ENABLE NOVALIDATE CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_NAME;
```

In first way we have explicitly mentioned Oracle to not validate the existing data at the time of creating the UNIQUE key and in second way we are initially marking the UNIQUE key as disable (it will not validate the data if we mark it disable)  and then enabling it using NOVALIDATE keyword

Comment: Only if the constraint is backed [by a non-unique index](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8005259/266304). If the index is unique (which is what you get by default) then it will still error.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for pointing it out but I am not sure if we can create a unique index on a column having duplicate data or not.

Comment: No you can't, and if you create a basic unique constraint a unique index will be created automatically - so it will fail if duplicate values exist. You can specify an existing index as part of the constraint definition, usually a unique one - say from dropping and recreating the constraint, without having to rebuild the index. But it doesn't have to be unique, as Jon showed in the answer I linked to.

Comment: Yeah if neither of the unique/non unique index is not created on a column on which a unique constraint is getting applied then Oracle will automatically create a unique index for that column